# Resolve string of hostname to string of IP

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an iPhone app and I need to resolve a string of a hostname into a string of an IP address. For example, "MyComputer.local" -> "192.168.0.7". I have tried doing a few things, but none have worked. This is what I have right now:

```
struct hostent *hostentry;
hostentry = gethostbyname("MyComputer.local");
char *ipbuf = NULL;
inet_ntop(AF_INET, hostentry->h_addr_list[0], ipbuf, hostentry->h_length);
ipAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s" , ipbuf];
```

For some reason, it always crashes on the inet_ntop, and yes, I am using an existing hostname to test. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of `inet_ntop` try `inet_ntoa`.

It helps to break compound statements up a little:

```
struct hostent *hostentry;
hostentry = gethostbyname("zaph.com");
NSLog(@"name: %s", hostentry->h_name);

struct in_addr **addr_list;
addr_list = (struct in_addr **)hostentry->h_addr_list;
char* ipAddr = inet_ntoa(*addr_list[0]);

NSString *ipAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", ipAddr];
NSLog(@"ipAddress: %@", ipAddress);
```

Output:

> name: zaph.com
>   ipAddress: 72.35.89.108